# Passing API call details by static props

Tags: vue.js

I'm building a small Vue.js app that needs several different API calls. I'm using tmdb api and I want to have popular, upcoming and top rated movies sections in my app. All these use the same call, which is (for popular in this case):

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=api_key&language=en-US&page=1
```

(popular can be replaced with top_rated or upcoming)

I have created component for the above call and on my main page I'm passing static props to this component to get the data I want:

```
<Movies type="popular"/>
<Movies type="upcoming"/>
<Movies type="top_rated"/>
```

I accept props and then put it in the link in fetch in the component as this:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.type}?api_key=api_key&language=en-US&page=1
```

Is this the right approach or should I just put all of the calls for popular, upcoming and top rated in Promise.all on my main page? Also I use these only on the main page and nowhere else in the app.

EDIT: I think that the main benefit of doing this in component is that I have to use only one for loop instead of 3. Still not sure if that's the right approach.

Comment: Passing the type as prop could be useful when it needs to be dynamic like
```data() {
 return {
  type : 'popular'
 }
}

<Movies :type="type" />
```
So you only need to make one API Call for the current `type` and not for all 3 all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is good approach. Each component is firing its own request and is rendered (updated) when that request is resolved independently of other instances of the component.

Using `Promise.all` doesn't make sense - is it important to have data from all 3 calls at the same time ? No...

You doing right :)

Comment: Great, thanks for reply. I can sleep peacefully now ;)